# In the spirit of the holidays

Tags: discussion

I've noticed a few threads have become a little heated as of late. Since the days are getting shorter up here in the northern hemisphere in preparation for all the solstice themed holidays, and a few folks may be getting a bit testy, I am kindly asking that before posting, you count to 10, take a few deep breaths, or whatever your stress coping mechanism maybe, and just move on.  All in the spirit of Peace on Earth.

Please and thank you.

**EDIT TO ADD**: As a bit of extra levity, post an answer with a funny meme, and the one that makes me laugh the most gets to be the selected answer to this.

[image: SERENITY NOW]

Comment: And if you are so inclined, smoking a blunt is perfectly acceptable behaviour. :)

Answer (score 21):

[image: hoping for fun]

Comment: Excellent sentiment. :)

Answer (score 17):

My contribution:

[image: Ho ho ho]

Comment: You can't get the answer because you are a personal friend of mine, but thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 13):

[image]

Comment: Reminds me about being a Program Manager. It's just  like riding a bike, except the bike is on fire, you're on fire, everything is on fire because you're in hell! :)

Comment: https://thenib.com/this-is-not-fine

Answer (score 2):

Now for one very relevant to this site...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I made this one my self (actually, the concept came from somewhere else, but I remade it into a HD version):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, last one, I promise.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No best answer yet? Finally, my time to shine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Again, pretty topical.

[image]